# R: Synchronizing time series (xts) objects

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I need to process a couple of hundreds of time series which roughly correspond to similar measurements, but with different people and on different days.

The time stamps have already been converted to POSIX format.

My problem is that I want to ignore the fact that the time series have been sampled at different days and different starting hours. In other words, I want to reformat the time series such that they count seconds from exactly the same start time, so that it will be easier to compare them.

Here is an example for two series:

Times of Series 1:

```
"2015-10-15 07:48:59 CEST", "2015-10-15 07:49:59 CEST", "2015-10-15 07:50:59 CEST", ...
```

Times of Series 2:

```
"2015-10-17 02:08:59 CEST", "2015-10-17 02:09:59 CEST", "2015-10-17 02:10:59 CEST", ...
```

Both series should be mapped to a kind of standard time framework, as e.g.

```
"2000-01-01 09:00:00 CEST", "2000-01-01 09:00:01 CEST", "2000-01-01 09:00:02 CEST", ...
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to subtract the first index value from each index, respectively. For example:

```
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix, dateFormat="Date")
head(x)
#                Open     High      Low    Close
# 2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
# 2007-01-03 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
# 2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
# 2007-01-05 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
# 2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
# 2007-01-07 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185
index(x) <- index(x) - unclass(start(x))
head(x)
#                Open     High      Low    Close
# 1970-01-01 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
# 1970-01-02 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
# 1970-01-03 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
# 1970-01-04 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
# 1970-01-05 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
# 1970-01-06 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, how would that work if I'd like to map the start of a times series to a single POSIXct object: ref.start <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 09:00:00")

Comment: Simply add that number of seconds to the index.